# Convert long name to short name in NANT?

Tags: nant

I am working on a NANT build project to build a VS project. One of the build file has a property definition like this:

```
<property name="App.dir" 
  value ="${directory::get-current-directory()}\Source\App"/>
```

This property value has been used in many other places. For example:

```
<exec program=".\test.exe"  workingdir=".">
  <arg line="${App.dir}\project1\resources\res1.resx /arg2"/>
```

Here I need to use <arg line=...> instead of <arg value=...> is to pass specified 2 arguments to text.exe.

when I build this NANT project on another developer's machine, I got a build failure. Finally I found out that the ${App.dir} on that developer's machine is a path in long-form and there is a space in the path. As a result, the arguments to text.exe were actually 3 or more.

I am not sure if there is any way to convert the ${App.dir} path to short name with no spaces:

```
<property name="App.dir" value ="????"/>
```

where ???? is something to convert "${directory::get-current-directory()}\Source\App" to a path name in a short-form. Is there any way to do that?

I am using NANT in Windows XP. In Unix/Cgywin, there is [one function](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/cygpath.get-dos-path%28System.String%29.html) to get dos name:

```
cygpath::get-dos-path
```

Can I use this one in my NANT build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <arg value="">, from the [NANT docs](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html):

value - A single command-line argument; can contain space characters.

Comment: whatever values in the arg will be passed to my regsgen to run. The spaces in the arg caused the issue.

Comment: if you use <arg value="..."> the value will be quoted automatically if neccessary. As an alternative you could use <arg path="...">.

Comment: The value attribute will take the whole value as ONE parameter. If there is space in the value, it will add quotes around value. My question is to pass the value as argument to my exec exe program. if the value of ${app.dir} is a part in <arg value=...> or <arg line=...>, the arguments are interpreted wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found two ways to resolve the issue. Instead of converting path to DOS path (8.3 name), I can use quotes around my arguments. The second method is the one as [ovado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370589/orvado) recommened to use <arg value=.../> for a single argument value.  Here is my test example. All the test files are in my *C:\Test* folder.  First, I created a test bat:

```
@REM This is the content of Test.bat file.
@echo COMMAND PARAMETERS: %*
@echo FIRST PARAMETER: %1
@echo SECOND PARAMETER: %2
dir %1
```

Then I created a test build file (Test.Build)"

```
<project>
  <target name="Test" description="Test with one line" failonerror="true">
    <property name="App.dir" value ="C:\Program Files"/>
    <exec program="test.bat"  workingdir=".">
      <arg line='"${App.dir}\Microsoft*.*" ${App.dir}\test2 /test3' />
    </exec>
  </target>
  <target name="Test2" description="Test2 with values" failonerror="true">
    <property name="App.dir" value ="C:\Program Files"/>
    <exec program="test.bat"  workingdir=".">
      <arg value="${App.dir}\Microsoft*.*" />
      <arg value="${App.dir}\test2" />
      <arg value="/test3" />
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

Here I used " to close my first argument in *<arg ='"..."' .../>*. Notice that I used single quote for my attribute *line*.

In this way, I run my build by *NANT.EXE*. I got the result as I expected:

```
C:\Test>NANT.exe -buildfile:test.build Test

Test:
   [exec] COMMAND PARAMETERS: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft*.*" C:\Program Files\test2 /test3
   [exec] FIRST PARAMETER: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft*.*"
   [exec] SECOND PARAMETER: C:\Program
   [exec] C:\Test\>dir "C:\Program Files\Microsoft*.*"
   [exec]  Volume in drive C has...
   ....
```

I got the same result with the alternative Test2,

```
C:\Test>NANT.exe -buildfile:test.build Test2
...
```